# Collection View from Core Data- Last Selected Appears First

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview, nsarray

**Current Functionality**

I have a collection view where each cell is composed of an image and a label. It is a collection view within a view controller. Currently the view compiles and loads up fine from two arrays (one for image names, one for label names). When the user taps a cell, it brings them to a new view controller.

**Desired Functionality**

However, I would like to add the functionality that when the user returns to the collection view the cell they tapped is now 1st (top left position). This new order should be saved to core data and become the new default order.

**Progress to Date**

I've started the process of trying to implement this function, but getting the original arrays into CoreData is proving challenging. I can't get the original arrays into CoreData and the collectionView building from the CoreData fetch. The collection view builds but none of my images / labels are there, only some CoreData code loaded into my labels...

Here's what I've got in my viewDidLoad:

```
    //Fetch & sort the list from Core Data
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MenuItem_llcv")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "displayOrder", ascending: true )
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [ sortDescriptor ]
    var error: NSError?
    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]

    //Check fetch results
    //If fetch was successful, the results are assigned to the context object
    if let results = fetchedResults {
        ll_ColViewOrder_Context = results
        println("Fetch succesful, although possibly empty.")
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }

    //First-time user check
    //If CoreData has the arrays, do nothing. If it doesn't, load them in.
    if ll_ColViewOrder_Context.count > 8 {
        println("Fetch result: Previously stored list found in Core Data.")
    } else {
        //Set arrays to populate cells
        cvListNames = ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3", "Label 4", "Label 5"]

        cvListImgs = ["image1","image2","image3","image4","image5"]

        let entityVar =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MenuItem_llcv", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        let listItem = NSManagedObject(entity: entityVar!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        var numberToStore = 1

        for ea_Name in cvListNames {
            listItem.setValue(ea_Name, forKey: "name")
        }
        for ea_ImgName in cvListImgs {
            listItem.setValue(ea_ImgName, forKey: "imgName")
        }
        for ea_OrderNum in cvListImgs {
            listItem.setValue(numberToStore, forKey: "displayOrder")
            ++numberToStore
        }
        managedContext.save(nil)
        println("Context now contains \(ll_ColViewOrder_Context)")
    }
```

Here's what my table is building from:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LifeList_CollectionViewCell

    //Assign images
    let image = UIImage(named: "\(ll_ColViewOrder_Context[indexPath.row])")
    cell.cvCell_Image.image = image

    //Assign list names
    let title = "\(ll_ColViewOrder_Context[indexPath.row])"
    cell.cvCell_Name.text = title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating only one NSManagedObject, and then iterating through assigning values to each of its attributes.  But you still have only one object.  You need to create a new NSMO for each value in your array(s):

```
    //Set arrays to populate cells
    cvListNames = ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3", "Label 4", "Label 5"]
    cvListImgs = ["image1","image2","image3","image4","image5"]

    let entityVar =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MenuItem_llcv", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    for (index, value) in enumerate(cvListNames) {
        let listItem = NSManagedObject(entity: entityVar!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
        listItem.setValue(value, forKey: "name")
        let imageName = cvListImgs[index]
        listItem.setValue(imageName, forKey: "imgName")
        listItem.setValue(index, forKey: "displayOrder")
        ll_ColViewOrder_Context.append(listItem)
    }
    managedContext.save(nil)
    println("Context now contains \(ll_ColViewOrder_Context)")
```

I've used the `enumerate` function in order to get the `index` for each value in `cvListNames`.  This `index` can then be used both to lookup the corresponding image in `cvListImgs`, and to populate the `displayOrder` attribute.  I've also included a line to append each new NSMO to the array which underpins your collection view.

Also, in the code for populating the collection view, you need to use `valueForKey` to extract the values for the relevant attributes:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LifeList_CollectionViewCell
//Assign images
let currentObject = ll_ColViewOrder_Context[indexPath.row]
let imageName = currentObject.valueForKey("imgName")
let listName = currentObject.valueForKey("name")
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
cell.cvCell_Image.image = image
//Assign list names
cell.cvCell_Name.text = listName
```

Comment: You're the man @pbasdf I truly appreciate the many answers you've given to my different questions. The only tweak I had to make was 'var imageName: String = currentObject.valueForKey("imgName") as! String' because without the "as! String", I was getting an error saying I was trying to assign AnyObject. But besides that little detail, your code works great. To get the last selected cell to move to first in the list now, in the didSelectCell method I should just do an core data 'insert at position 1" and then delete the old object?

Comment: @DaveG You're welcome.  I forgot about casting the `valueForKey`.  You might want to investigate creating NSManagedObject subclasses for your entities, then you can use . accessors (`currentObject.imgName`) rather than `valueForKey`.  The compiler can then do the type-checking.

Comment: To move the selected cell isn't quite that easy.  Start by getting the table view to build correctly using a NSFetchedResultsController.  There is boilerplate code for that.  The idea is that the fetch underlying the FRC should be sorted using the `displayOrder`.  To move the item, don't delete and re-add the object, just amend its `displayOrder` attribute so that it is sorted before the other items.

Comment: Woohoo! Did it.         var newOrderNum = 1
        for eaObj in ll_ColViewOrder_Context {
            eaObj.setValue(newOrderNum, forKey: "displayOrder")
            ++newOrderNum
        } Thank you for the help!